# Computing the transition matrix of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, transition-matrix

Let $(Y_i)_{i\geq0}$ be i.i.d. random variables, following the uniform distribution in state space S = $\{1,...,6\}$. The goal is to show that the following sequence of random variables is a Markov Chain and compute both the initial distribution and the transition martix.

- the largest number $L_n$ shown so far.

First, we know the present, which is: $L_n = max\{Y_1,...,Y_n\}$. Then the future is $L_{n+1}=max\{L_n,Y_{n+1}\}$, which is independent of the past $\{L_0,...,L_{n-1}\}$, hence this sequence is indeed a Markov Chain.

- Initial distribution: $\mathbb{P}(L_0=x_0)=\mathbb{P}(Y_0=x_0)=1/6$ for $x_0\in S$ fixed.
- Transition Matrix: Fix $x,y\in S$, Q(x,y)=$\mathbb{P}(L_{n+1}=y|L_n=x)=
  \begin{cases}
  0\quad if \quad y<x,\\
  \frac{x}{6}\quad if \quad y=x \\
  \frac{1}{6}\quad if \quad y>x
  \end{cases}
  $

Here are my questions:

1. To get $\frac{1}{6}$ we need to compute: $\mathbb{P}(L_{n+1}=y|L_n=x)$. How do we compute this and get 1/6?
2. To get $\frac{x}{6}$ we have to compute: $\mathbb{P}(L_{n+1}=x|L_n=x)=\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1}\leq x)$. How do we come to $\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1}\leq x)$ and then how do we get to $\frac{x}{6}$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both straight forward from the definition of maximum: 1) $L_{n+1} = \max\{L_n, Y_{n+1}\} = y >  L_{n} \iff Y_{n+1} = y$; 2) $L_{n+1} = \max\{L_n, Y_{n+1}\} = x = L_{n} \iff Y_{n+1} \leq x$

Comment: In the transition matrix $\mathbf{Q},$ entry $q(x,y) = P(L_{n+1}=y |L_{n}=x)$ can you find $q(3,6)$ and $q(5,5)$ and explain why--in terms of rolling a fair die? What is the long-run behavior of this Markov chain? If you start in state 3, what is the expected number of rolls of the die until you get to state 6?